# Using Keras's Categorical Crossentropy loss the right way

Tags: python, keras, categorical-data

My model's output shape is

```
(batch_size, n_timesteps, n_outputs)
```

the last axis contains the outputs of a softmax layer, ranging over `n_outputs` classes.

I just want to be sure that Keras' `categorical_crossentropy` loss and `categorical_accuracy` metrics are computed timestep-wise and not in some weird way (e.g. over the flattened `n_timesteps*n_outputs` outputs, which would be very wrong).

How can I be sure of this?

Comment: You can just look at how it is implemented if you don't trust it (e.g. [here for TensorFlow](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/2.2.4/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py#L3258-L3298)), but that is the standard behavior of cross-entropy, not sure you should have any reason to expect it to behave differently.

Comment: It's still not very clear what they mean for "channels axis", but it seems indeed that the cross-entropy is applied to the last axis.